# HTTP POST - Json

Tags: angular

I am trying to post my json values in the nested format as  below but in my code, my data is submitted singly which is a constraint in the database. I select a number of doctors from my phone app and when i click save, the httpRequest much submit all the doctors selected singly as in the nested format. How can i submit the data in the nested format?

**my code**

```
Hospitals = {
  hospital : "New York hospital",
  doctor: {
     details: {  
      id: "",
      ward: ""          
     }
  }
}

//this is how i post to the server 
 saveDoctorsForHospitals(){   
    Object.keys(this.Doctors).filter(key => this.Doctors[key].find)
       .forEach(key => {
           this.Hospitals.Doctors.details.id = this.Docotrs[key].id
           this.Hospitals.Doctors.details.ward = this.Doctors[key].ward

    this.httpService.submitAll(this.Hospitals)
        .subscribe(data => {
           console.log(data);   
        })
```

**this is how my data is submitted now**

```
  object 1         
    "hospital" : "McJames",
    "Doctor" : {
       "1" : {
          "id": 1269,
          "ward": "Demarco",                    
       }        
  Object 2
     "hospital" : "McJames",
     "Doctor" : {
        "2" : {
           "id": 1269,
           "ward": "Demarco",     
        }


//but i want to be this 

    {
      "hospital" : "McJames",
      "Doctor" : {
         "1" : {
           "id": 1269,
            "ward": "Demarco",    
         },

         "2" : {
            "id": 1275,
            "ward": "Eden",
          }
        }
      }
```

**updated - wrapping in array**

```
Hospitals = {
  hospital : "New York hospital",
  doctor: [{
     details: {  
      id: "",
      ward: ""          
     }
  }]
}
```

Comment: `doctor: [{}]` to accept multiple doctor objects

Comment: @mrtaz can you be much clearer on your statement

Comment: you need to set up your doctor property on the Hospitals object to accept many doctors. You need to wrap doctor in an array, hence `doctor: [{}]`

Comment: @mrtaz please look at my updated code. In this instance i am not able to reach the details in my `saveDoctorsForHospital()`

Comment: you have `this.Hospitals.Doctors.details.id = this.Docotrs[key].id` you see Doctors is mispelled there. Also, 'Doctors' is not defined but 'doctor' is on your hospital object. Try `this.Hospitals.doctor['0'].details.id = this.doctor[key].id`

Comment: @mrtaz, i am able to reach the properties. What is this doing`this.Hospitals.doctor['0'].details.id = this.doctor[key].id`?

Comment: So `this.Hospitals.doctor['0'].details.id = this.doctor[key].id` is essentially accessing all the way down to the the details property. Key thing here is since we wrapped the doctor property in an array we can access the indexed objects, specifically the `['0']` of the doctor array which will allow you access into that object's property.

Comment: @mrtaz So i specified ['0'] for all other properties in the details and submitted. I selected two doctors and did an http post but it failed to submit the 2 selected doctors in one post but rather posted the 2nd doctor in a new request. Please look in the image uploaded

Comment: lets do chat real quick

Comment: @mrtaz, lets go on a discussion

Answer (score 1):

The code here:

```
Hospitals = {
  hospital : "New York hospital",
  doctor: {
     details: {  
      id: "",
      ward: ""          
     }
  }
}
```

Defines what you are posting. This data structure is saying that you have one hospital property with a string value and one doctor property that is an object. If you want multiple doctors, you'll need to change this structure such that the doctors are defined as an array.

You could use interfaces such as this:

```
interface Hospital {
    hospital: string;
    doctors: Doctors[]
}
interface Doctors {
    id: number,
    ward: string
}

class Test {
    hospitals: Hospital[] = [];
    constructor() {
        this.hospitals.push({
            hospital: "New York Hospital",
            doctors: [{
                id: 1269,
                ward: "test"
            }]
        })
    }
    data() {
        return JSON.stringify(this.hospitals);
    }
}
```